# Crashing on insert of data into an access database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I am working In c# and inserting my data into an Access database. It runs properly but crashes when I try to insert data, any idea why?

```
public partial class StudentInfo : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection myCon;

    public StudentInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\database program\database program\Students.mdb");
    } 


    private void InsertBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into StudentInfo(Rollno,SName,SFather,SAdress) Values ('"+ Rollnotb.Text+"','"+nametb.Text+"','"+fathertb.Text+"','"+adresstb.Text+"')";
        cmd.Connection=myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: its giving no error only crashing when i inserting data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be that you are inserting all fields as `text` values and maybe some are defined as numeric in the MS Access table (`rollNo`?)

Also, get used to using paremeters in your queries:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into StudentInfo(Rollno,SName,SFather,SAdress) Values (?,?,?,?)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@rollNo", rollNoValue)); //etc.
```